# Calculating a relationship between unique pairs of observations about a colum in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, rowwise

I am trying to calculate the probability, subject to proportion, of two commodities appearing in the same group.

I have the following data,

```
data <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                   commodity = c("Wheat", "Coal", "Steel", "Iron", "Wheat", "Coal", "Steel", "Iron", "Wheat", "Coal", "Steel", "Iron"),
                   quantity = c(5,10,0,5,20,5,10,0,0,10,15,15),
                   proportion = c(0.25,0.5,0,0.25,0.57,0.14,0.29,0,0,0.25,0.375,0.375))
```

I would like to do a calculation on the proportion (sum of products divided by 2) for each of the unique possible pairs of commodities.

The result should be something like this,

```
result <- data.frame(commodity1 = c("Wheat", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Coal", "Coal", "Steel"),
                     commodity2 = c("Coal", "Steel", "Iron", "Steel", "Iron", "Iron"),
                     result = c(0.103,0.082,0.031,0.067,0.109,0.070))
```

Where the result for Wheat - Coal for example, would be calculated (0.25 * 0.5/2)+(0.57 * 0.14/2)+(0 * 0.25/2)=0.103

I have isolated the commodity pairs into a separate data.frame to mutate the result into and attempted a rowwise() operation.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the product of proportions is divided by 2 for each within group pair

Comment: Did none of the answer serve the intended purpose?  You haven't accepted any of the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not much of clean, it seems working

```
library(tidyverse)

#make an intermediate data.frame say `dd`
data %>% select(-quantity) %>%
  pivot_longer(proportion) %>%
  select(-name, -group) %>%
  group_by(commodity) %>%
  nest(data = c(value)) -> dd


t(combn(unique(data$commodity), 2)) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(result = map2_dbl(V1, V2, 
                        ~ sum(unlist(dd$data[match(.x, dd$commodity)]) * unlist(dd$data[match(.y, dd$commodity)]))/2
                      )
         )

     V1    V2    result
1 Wheat  Coal 0.1024000
2 Wheat Steel 0.0826500
3 Wheat  Iron 0.0312500
4  Coal Steel 0.0671750
5  Coal  Iron 0.1093750
6 Steel  Iron 0.0703125
```

Comment: Thank you kindly Anil, this is a really great solution

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(commodity1 = data$commodity, commodity2 = data$commodity, group = data$group) %>%
  filter(commodity1 < commodity2) %>%
  left_join(data, by = c("commodity1" = "commodity", "group")) %>%
  left_join(data, by = c("commodity2" = "commodity", "group")) %>%
  mutate(avg = proportion.x * proportion.y / 2) %>%
  group_by(commodity1, commodity2) %>%
  summarize(result = sum(avg), .groups = "drop")


# A tibble: 6 x 3
  commodity1 commodity2 result
* <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
1 Coal       Iron       0.109 
2 Coal       Steel      0.0672
3 Coal       Wheat      0.102 
4 Iron       Steel      0.0703
5 Iron       Wheat      0.0312
6 Steel      Wheat      0.0826
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really an excellent solution, Ive been meaning to solve this problem for quite some time.